# It says "add / show 2 more comments" but there is only one comment under there.

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment

This is minor. I'm using firefox on a Macintosh. I see this:

[image]

Here: [Human checkable proof of the Four Color Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/human-checkable-proof-of-the-four-color-theorem)

It says "add / show 2 more comments" ... but when I click there is only **one** comment under there. (Mine.)

Are other people seeing the same issue?

UPDATE: As soon as I posted this a 2nd comment showed up. *This must just be a lag* issue of some kind. It was going on for a good 15min where I saw "add / show 2 more comments" but there was only one comment there.

If this is now pointless we can delete.

Whenever I describe a problem it goes away.

Comment: "Whenever I describe a problem it goes away." Do us all a favor and describe global warming.

Answer (score 1):

The counts can be slightly off from time to time -- this is not unheard of and not totally abnormal.

It should not be *common* however.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I've seen happen is that some of the hidden comments are in the middle of the queue, and not at the end, so there might (for example) be seven more comments, but only two appended after the last visible comment.

Comment: I believe this is deliberate - comments with lots of up-votes take priority. For example, in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good) the top comment before they are unhidden is *not* the first posted.

Comment: But it is quite confusing, especially if the visible comments implicitly refer to previous comments which are not shown.